# Segmentation fault in gsoap when use inheritance in soap_ssl_server_context(...)

Tags: c++, qt, ssl, gsoap

I have set up a gsoap web service and it works. I need to use SSL. I follow steps as mention in the following link :
https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/index.html#serveropenssl
and my program is crashed :(

Soap files are generated with 'soapcpp2 -i' switch that inherits from soap class.

My QT .pro file:

```cpp
...
LIBS += -lgsoapssl++ -lssl -lcrypto
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DWITH_OPENSSL
...
```

And finally, my program was crashed at following function "soap_ssl_server_context" even with NULL parameter for all arguments.

```
  if (soap_ssl_server_context(soap, 
    SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT, 
    "server.pem",      /* keyfile: required when server must authenticate to clients (see SSL docs on how to obtain this file) */ 
    "password",        /* password to read the key file (not used with GNUTLS) */ 
    "cacert.pem",      /* optional cacert file to store trusted certificates */ 
    NULL,              /* optional capath to directory with trusted certificates */ 
    "dh512.pem",       /* DH file name or DH key len bits (minimum is 512, e.g. "512") to generate DH param, if NULL use RSA */ 
    NULL,              /* if randfile!=NULL: use a file with random data to seed randomness */  
    NULL               /* optional server identification to enable SSL session caching to speed up TLS (must be a unique name) */
  )) 
  {
    soap_print_fault(soap, stderr); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, after I convert my Gsoap service to use SSL, I didn't remove libgsoap++ and append libgsoapssl++. So the application crashed :|